# pytest - getting the value of fixture parameter

Tags: python, pytest

Is there a way to save the value of parameter, provided by pytest fixture:

Here is an example of conftest.py

```
# content of conftest.py

import pytest

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--parameter", action="store", default="default",
                     help="configuration file path")

@pytest.fixture
def param(request):
    parameter = request.config.getoption("--parameter")
    return parameter
```

Here is an example of pytest module:

```
# content of my_test.py

def test_parameters(param):
    assert param == "yes"
```

OK - everything works fine, but is there a way to get the value of `param` outside the test - for example with some build-in pytest function `pytest.get_fixture_value["parameter"]`

**EDITED - DETAILED EXPLANATION WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEV**

I am writing an module, that deploys and after that provides parameters to tests, writen in pytest. My idea is if someones test looks like that:

```
class TestApproachI:
    @load_params_as_kwargs(parameters_A)
    def setup_class(cls, param_1, param_2, ... , param_n):
        # code of setup_class

    def teardown_class(cls):
        # some code

    def test_01(self):
        # test code
```

And this someone gives me a configuration file, that explains with what parameters to run his code, I will analyze those parameters (in some other script) and I will run his tests with the command `pytest --parameters=path_to_serialized_python_tuple test_to_run` where this tuple will contain the provided values for this someone parameters in the right order. And I will tell that guy (with the tests) to add this decorator to all the tests he wants me to provide parameters. This decorator would look like this:

```
class TestApproachI:
    # this path_to_serialized_tuple should be provided by 'pytest --parameters=path_to_serialized_python_tuple test_to_run'
    @load_params(path_to_serialized_tuple) 
    def setup_class(cls, param_1, param_2, ... , param_n):
        # code of setup_class

    def teardown_class(cls):
        # some code

    def test_01(self):
        # test code
```

The decorator function should look like that:

```
def load_params(parameters):
    def decorator(func_to_decorate):
        @wraps(func_to_decorate)
        def wrapper(self):
            # deserialize the tuple and decorates replaces the values of test parameters
            return func_to_decorate(self, *parameters)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Comment: Why would you want to do get the value outside of a test?

Comment: @Nils Werner It is complicated to be explained, but if you want I will edit my question

Comment: Well, you have only established what works. Not what you are trying to do and doesn't work.

Comment: @ Nils Werner I added detailed info for what I want to solve

Comment: Why don't you put the loading logic in a fixture and have the person just request that loader fixture?

Comment: @Nils Werner I thought of that, but there would be a lot of code changing in the tests:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144567/discussion-between-stefan-stt-and-nils-werner).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set that `parameter` as os environment variable, and than use it anywhere in your test through `os.getenv('parameter')`

So, you can use like,

```
@pytest.fixture
def param(request):
    parameter = request.config.getoption("--parameter")
    os.environ["parameter"]=parameter 
    return parameter

@pytest.mark.usefixtures('param')
def test_parameters(param):
    assert os.getenv('parameter') == "yes"
```

Comment: It doesn't work like that - `os.getenv('parameter')` returns None: `AssertionError: assert None == 'yes'`

Answer (score 2):

I am using `pytest-lazy-fixture` to get the value any fixture:

- first install it using `pip install pytest-lazy-fixture` or `pipenv install pytest-lazy-fixture`
- then, simply assign the fixture to a variable like this if you want:

```
    fixture_value = pytest.lazy_fixture('fixture')
```

*the fixture has to wrapped with quotations*

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pytest function config.cache, like this

```
def function_1(request):
  request.config.cache.set("user_data", "name")
  ...

def function_2(request):
  request.config.cache.get("user_data", None)
  ...
```

Here is more info about it

https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#std-fixture-cache
https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/cache.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).